# What is better way to design models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have model **Domain** and I need to check DNS records for each domain. I have two options

1. create model **DnsRecord** with fields `record_type(A, CNAME,
   etc), domain_id, check_result, timestamps`
2. use field jsonb for
       **Domain** and save all records in this field

In first case table dns_records will contain a lot of records, but in seconds case not very convenient to work with data
What option is better? Does anybody know better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first option is the best because you could manipulate it individualy. If you put everithing in a json you probably will have probles on handle with this data soon. I could not think another solution for this problem. sorry.